# How to switch flutter page in navbar

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm doing a school project  and I need help, I made the codes I'll show you in the image, but I'm not able to link the calendar in the navigation bar, here is a part of the code where I wanted to make the link

```
     ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.calendar_month,
            color: Color.fromARGB(255, 1, 32, 58),
            ),
            title: Text('Calendário'),
            onTap: () => print('Calendartap') ,
          ),
```

if you can help me I'd be very grateful

[image]

Att;
delay1014

I tried so hard and got so far
But in the end it all went wrong

Comment: It is hard to tell from current context. If you like to change/land on different page(route), you need to use [navigator;example code](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics) 

and You can check [BottomNavigationBar example](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the Stackoverflow.
Flutter does not look easy to get started, but I assure you I've seen some kids learn it pretty fast, and if you put some work into trying to understand the basics, you will be able to do cool things with what you've learned.

There are several ways to open a **Widget**, a new **Route**, or a **Screen**.

To create a screen with a new widget you just need to call an action with this code:

```
Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const SecondRoute()),
            );
```

Here is a full example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(
    title: 'Navigation Basics',
    home: FirstRoute(),
  ));
}

class FirstRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  const FirstRoute({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('First Route'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          child: const Text('Open route'),
          onPressed: () {
            // THIS CODE OPENS/ ADDS A NEW SCREEN / WIDGET
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const SecondRoute()),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  const SecondRoute({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Second Route'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            // THIS ACTION REMOVES / CLOSES THE CURRENT WIDGET
            // FROM THE VIEW
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          child: const Text('Go back!'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**BONUS**:
Here are some useful links for you to follow and learn more about flutter:

.  [Flutter Cookbook](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook)
.  [Flutter Codelabs](https://docs.flutter.dev/codelabs)